# Text-Align right <select> with text that starts with a number

Tags: html, css

I would like to have my `<select>` element to have my text aligned to the right. This can be achieved by using one of the following solutions:

**CSS** : `select{direction: rtl}`

**HTML ATTRIBUTE** : `<select dir="rtl">`

This works fine in the majority of situations, but there is a small annoying hiccup in a certain edge case.

The hiccup happens when you do the following :

```
<select dir="rtl">
    <option value="1">1 Month</option>
    <option value="2">2 Months</option>
</select>
```

So note that my `<option>` elements start with a **Number**. When using `dir="rtl"` the number is moved to the right, the rest of the sentence is respected.

So the output will be like:

- Month 1
- Months 2

Now if you prefix with a word, like :

```
<select dir="rtl">
    <option value="1">Some Prefix 1 Month</option>
    <option value="2">Some Prefix 2 Months</option>
</select>
```

The output will be like:

- Some Prefix 1 Month
- Some Prefix 2 Months

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.form {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 400px;
}

.form__row {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin 1rem auto 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form__row>div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.form__row .label {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.form__row .input {
  padding-right: 1rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.form__row select {
  width: 100%;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  direction: rtl;
}

.form__row input {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=form>
  <div class="form__row">
    <div class="label">Your Name : </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="your name" value="This aligns right nicely">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form__row">
    <div class="label">How long : </div>
    <div class="input">
      <select>
          <option value="1">1 Month</option>
          <option value="2">2 Months</option>
          <option value="1">Prefixed 1 Month</option>
          <option value="2">Prefixed 2 Months</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can check **[fiddle here](https://codepen.io/segersian/project/editor/AgbRjy#0)**

I think this is related with how 'right-to-left' (Arabic, Hebrew, ...) languages probably work with numbers. I recall reading once that they tend to have some certain rules regarding how numbers are placed or so.

**TL;DR / Summary**

Is there an alternative way to text align to the right with a `<select>` element? Or a clean workaround? I can change my numbers to written numbers (one, two, ...), but I was hoping for another alternative. Because in my case the numbers go up to 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is proper way with your own code**

This will work for you -

Just use `direction: ltr;` in your `<option>` and all will work fine:

```
.form__row select option {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.form {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 400px;
}

.form__row {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin 1rem auto 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form__row>div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.form__row .label {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.form__row .input {
  padding-right: 1rem;
  text-align: right;
}

.form__row select {
  width: 100%;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  direction: rtl;
}

.form__row select option {
    direction: ltr;
}
.form__row input {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class=form>
  <div class="form__row">
    <div class="label">Your Name : </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="your name" value="This aligns right nicely">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form__row">
    <div class="label">How long : </div>
    <div class="input">
      <select>
          <option value="1">1 Month</option>
          <option value="2">2 Months</option>
          <option value="1">Prefixed 1 Month</option>
          <option value="2">Prefixed 2 Months</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great alternative to @lumio 's answer. Makes the drop down even more consistent! Thanks!

Comment: @IanSegers glad I could be helpful this is the proper way to apply `direction:` to `<select>` or different browser will render the select box differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your select text to be right but don't care about the options, you could use `text-align-last: right`:

```css
select {
  text-align-last: right;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">1 Month</option>
    <option value="2">2 Months</option>
</select>
```

or if it doesn't matter that the arrows are on the left as well, you could combine `rtl` for the `<select>` and `ltr` for the `<option>`:

```css
select {
  direction: rtl;
}

select option {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="1">1 Month</option>
    <option value="2">2 Months</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @IanSegers this is not supported by **Safari** , Refer Link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-align-last.asp

Answer (score 0):

what about ?

```
 <select style="text-align:right">
    <option  value="1">1 Month</option>
    <option value="2">2 Months</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That one has no effect :) on a `<select>` or `<option>` element

Comment: sry there was typo in align